# Optional function arguments with no default value possible?

Tags: optional-parameters, keyword-argument, chapel

In Chapel, we can set the default value of function formal arguments easily, for example,

```
proc test( a = 1, b = 2.0, c = "hi" ) {
    ...
}
```

and call the function by using keywords also:

```
test( 10 );         // a = 10, b = 2.0,  c = "hi"
test( b = 3.14 );   // a = 1,  b = 3.14, c = "hi"
test( c = "yo" );   // a = 1,  b = 2.0,  c = "yo"
```

Here, I am wondering if it is possible to define a keyword argument that does not require a predefined default value. More specifically, I would like to write a function that can optionally receive an array depending on cases (e.g., to save intermediate data). Here, the only requirement is that I can check whether the actual argument is passed or not, and there is no need to give the default array value. I imagined something like

```
proc test( ..., optional d: [] real ) {
    if present( d ) then ...;
}

or

proc test( ..., d: [] real = None ) {
    if present( d ) then ...;
}
```

but was not able to find similar things. At the moment, my workaround is to give some dummy default value and check their properties to determine whether an actual argument is passed.

```
proc test( arr = empty2Dreal ) { ... }  // where "empty2Dreal" is a pre-defined global array
or
proc test( arr = reshape( [0.0], {1..1,1..1} ) ) { ... } // some dummy array
}
```

However, I am wondering whether there might be a more elegant(?) or idiomatic(?) approach...

### Edit

As suggested in the comment, it is also convenient to overload several functions to get different interfaces, but at some point I guess I need to pass some "dummy" object to the final (full-fledged) routine and ask the latter to see if the passed object is "dummy" or not... MWE is something like this:

```
const empty1Dint: [1..0] int;

proc test( x: real, arr: [] int )
{
    writeln("test() with 2 args");
    writeln(( x, arr ));

    // here, I need to check whether the passed object is
    // an actual array or not by some predefined rule
    if arr.size > 0 then writeln("got a non-empty array");
}

proc test( x: real )
{
    writeln("test() with 1 arg");
    test( x = x, arr = empty1Dint );
}

var work = [1,2,3,4,5];

test( x = 1.0 );

writeln();
test( x = 1.0, arr = work );
```

which gives

```
test() with 1 arg
test() with 2 args
(1.0, )

test() with 2 args
(1.0, 1 2 3 4 5)
got a non-empty array
```

The corresponding default-value version is

```
const empty1Dint: [1..0] int;

proc test( x: real, arr: [] int = empty1Dint )
{
    writeln("test() with 2 args");
    writeln(( x, arr ));

    if arr.size > 0 then writeln("got a non-empty array");
}

var work = [1,2,3,4,5];

test( x = 1.0 );
writeln();
test( x = 1.0, arr = work );
```

which gives

```
test() with 2 args
(1.0, )

test() with 2 args
(1.0, 1 2 3 4 5)
got a non-empty array
```

Although the above approach works for arrays, the rule needs to change depending on the type of objects used. So, I was wondering if there is some systematic way, e.g., to pass a "null pointer" or some unique global object to tell the final routine about the presence of the actual data. (But, as noted above, the above approach works for arrays).

### Edit 2

Another approach may be simply to pass an additional flag for using the passed array (then there is no need to think much about the nature of the default object, so may be overall simpler...)

```
const empty1Dint: [1..0] int;

proc test( x: real, arr: [] int = empty1Dint, use_arr = false )
{
    writeln( "x= ", x );

    if use_arr {
        writeln("working with the passed array...");
        for i in 1..arr.size do arr[ i ] = i * 10;
    }
}

test( x = 1.0 );
writeln();

var work: [1..5] int;
test( x = 2.0, arr = work, use_arr = true );
writeln( "work = ", work );
```

### Edit 3

Following Option 3 in the answer, here is a modified version of my code using `_void` and `void`:

```
proc test( x: real, arr: ?T = _void )
{
    writeln( "\ntest():" );
    writeln( "x        = ", x );
    writeln( "arr      = ", arr );
    writeln( "arr.type = ", arr.type:string );
    writeln( "T        = ", T:string );

    if arr.type != void {
        writeln( "doing some checks" );
        assert( isArray( arr ) );
    }

    if arr.type != void {
        writeln( "writing arr" );
        for i in 1..arr.size do arr[ i ] = i * 10;
    }
}

// no optional arg
test( x = 1.0 );

// use an optional arg
var work: [1..5] int;
test( x = 2.0, arr = work );

writeln( "\nmain> work = ", work );
```

Result:

```
test():
x        = 1.0
arr      = 
arr.type = void
T        = void

test():
x        = 2.0
arr      = 0 0 0 0 0
arr.type = [domain(1,int(64),false)] int(64)
T        = [domain(1,int(64),false)] int(64)
doing some checks
writing arr

main> work = 10 20 30 40 50
```

Comment: Would overloading the function suit your purpose?  E.g. defining a second version of test that doesn't take the array argument and then calls the other one with an empty local array?

Comment: Thank your very much, I didn't think of overloading at all, so I have just tried it. However, it seems to me that I need to pass a similar dummy object at some point of sequential function calls (so after all, I need to define such a dummy object (like `empty1Dint`) + define a local rule for judging the presence of actual data). But, for the latter purpose, it might be useful to define some unique global type and its object (like None type) and overload assignment with it (not sure at all though...)

Comment: I wanted to add that if you weren't satisfied by solutions proposed here and thought there was a reasonable extension to Chapel that would make patterns like this easier / clearer to write, that you should definitely feel free to propose it on our GitHub issues page:  https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer discusses 3 answers:

1. The strategy discussed in the edit of the question.
2. A strategy using a `Box` type
3. A strategy using a generic function with a void default value

My favorite of these options is Option 3.

#### Option 1

`proc test( x: real, arr: [] int = empty1Dint, use_arr = false )` strategy described in the question is reasonable, if a little verbose. The main drawback here is that you'd need more overloads of `test` if you didn't want the call sites to have to pass `use_arr=true` or `use_arr=false`. Here is a simple program that does that:

```
proc test(optional, hasOptional:bool) {
  writeln("in test");
  writeln("  optional is ", optional);
  if hasOptional == false then
    writeln("  note: default was used for optional");
}

proc test(optional) {
  test(optional, hasOptional=true);
}
proc test() {
  var emptyArray:[1..0] int;
  test(emptyArray, hasOptional=false);
}


test();
test([1, 2, 3]);
```

#### Option 2

Another alternative is to create a class to store the optional argument data, and pass nil by default.

```
class Box {
  var contents;
}

proc makeArray() {
  var A:[1..2] int;
  return A;
}

proc emptyBox() {
  var A:[1..0] int;
  var ret: owned Box(A.type) = nil;
  return ret;
}

proc test( optional=emptyBox() ) {
  writeln("in test with optional=", optional);
}

test();
test(new owned Box(makeArray()));
```

Here the main tricky part is that the array type returned by makeArray() and emptyBox() have to match. It'd be possible to use a type alias to have them refer to the same array type, but how exactly that would fit in depends on your application. Another problem with this approach is that it causes the array to be copied in the process of passing such an argument. And, one has to think about where the `Box` will be destroyed. Is `test` to hang on to the array value (e.g. storing it in a data structure) or just going to use it temporarily? This is set by the type returned by `emptyBox` in my example.

It's probably reasonable for the standard library to gain such a `Box` type but it doesn't have one now.

#### Option 3

My favorite solution to this problem is a third strategy altogether.
Chapel includes [a value of void type called _void](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/technotes/voidVariables.html). The key is the declaration `proc test( optional:?t=_void )`. Here `test` is a generic function - the syntax `argument:?t` indicates that the argument can have a varied type (which will be available as `t` within the function). This is necessary to get a generic argument that also has a default value (otherwise the argument will have only the type inferred from the default value).

If no `optional` argument is provided, it will instantiate with `optional` having type `void`. Which makes sense as a way to not pass something. Technically it's not the same as checking if the default value was provided, but I think a call site like `test(optional=_void)` is reasonably clear at communicating that the value of `optional` should be ignored (since it's `void`).

Anyway here is the code:

```
proc test( optional:?t=_void ) {
  writeln("in test");
  writeln("  optional is ", optional);
  if optional.type == void then
    writeln("  note: default was used for optional");
}

test();
test([1, 2, 3]);
```

Comment: Oog, this is a good reminder that we really need to come up with a better name for the `void` value than `_void`...

It also seems like this solution might be improved by adding a where clause to restrict to to either `t` or the `void` type to prevent any old thing from being passed in?

Comment: Yes. My answer was intentionally generic but it would indeed be reasonable to use a where clause to restrict the type in a more general setting. I found writing the array types to be distracting from the main idea in my answer.

Comment: @mppf Thanks very much! I think the option 3 is exactly what I was looking for (I've attached a modified version of my code in Edit 3). The option 2 also seems nice, so I will try it when it seems more appropriate than option 2.